Objects get stuck in each other
I was trying to do a simulation of money falling on the floor, and the problem is that as soon as it touches the floor, some of it gets stuck in each other

I used Collision for the floor and Cloth for the money.
I tried different settings, but the result is the same.



I'm a newbie, so I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong


thanks for the file but I can't see what's the problem with it?

@moonboots I forgot to switch Eevee to Cycles. In Cycles mode, you may notice that the banknotes get stuck in each other

I created something similar, first of all I would recommend you increase the Quality Steps in the general Cloth settings and also the Quality under Collisions. I have set both to 25, but probably it is not necessary to go so high.
The most important step which will drastically improve the interaction between the bank notes is the following: join them all together with Ctrl+J so that they are a single object. It does not matter that they are separate meshes, when they combined to a single cloth object the enabled Self Collision will take care of the separate pieces not going through each other. Maybe not perfect, but much better than if they were separate objects, especially when they are lying on the ground.
This is my initial result - as you can see, the notes jump a little weird which I realized after rendering. That's why sometimes too many quality are not always better, I reduced them to 10 afterwards and set Impulse Clamping under Self Collisions to 0.1 for a better result.

And these are my settings just for completeness, although the main trick is the joining of meshes as I said (I marked where I have different values than you - although I forgot to mention the bend stiffness, I've set that higher too because money is not very flexible):


Thank you, it really worked

@Jill Obviously not good enough as you did not accept my answer. Sure, you can increase the distance to 0.01 m like in the other answer, but this can result in banknotes seemingly hovering above each other... if that's what you want... apart from that: when I tested the other solution with your file, the notes were still stuck in each other.

@GordonBrinkmann No, it really did help, and I clicked accept. i didn't realize you could only select one answer, I just noticed that.

@GordonBrinkmann Result

Delete the Bake, apply the scale of the bills and increase the Object Collisions distance a bit:

Result in Cycles:

File: 

Maybe it works different on your computer, but when I try that the notes are still piercing through each other in Cycles:  Cycles version, while in EEVEE it depends on the viewing angle which one is visible on top: EEVEE version.

It seems to work fine in Cycles but maybe doing as you did (using one only object) gives better result

Strange, on my PC applying these changes gave more or less the same result as if I did not change anything.
